# Thyme leaf dropdown list without preselecting

Tags: thymeleaf

I have several drop down lists in my Thymeleaf pages that look such as:

```
 <select name="institution.serviceDept" th:field="*{serviceDept}">
      <option th:each="choice : ${serviceDeptList}"
              th:value="${choice.serviceDeptId}"
              th:attr="choiceinstitutionId=${choice.serviceDeptId}, institutioninstitutionId=*{serviceDept.serviceDeptId}, 
              showselected=(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})"
             th:selected="(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})"
             th:readonly="(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})"
             th:text="${choice.name}"></option>
   </select>
```

When I view the page, the first value in the list appears selected, and in fact is submitted as the selected value even if its not selected manually.  I would prefer to nothing selected by default unless it has already been selected.  I removed the " th:selected" and that doesn't make any difference.

Can anyone tell me how to either have nothing selected or perhaps a default value such as "Please select" ?

Answer (score 2):

Posting my answer here, as the others didn't work for me (but your mileage my vary).  Apparently you can't use a null, or a dummy object in your list or all sorts of exceptions are thrown.  What you can do is adding another blank `<option></option>` like this:

```
<select name="institution.serviceDept" th:field="*{serviceDept}">
     <option th:value="0" text="Please Select"></option>
      <option th:each="choice : ${serviceDeptList}" 
              th:value="${choice.serviceDeptId}" 
              th:attr="choiceinstitutionId=${choice.serviceDeptId}, institutioninstitutionId=*{serviceDept.serviceDeptId}, 
              showselected=(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})" 
             th:selected="(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})" 
             th:readonly="(${choice.serviceDeptId} == *{serviceDept.serviceDeptId})" 
             th:text="${choice.name}"></option>
   </select>
```

Note the lack of `th` on the dummy option tag, and a `th:value`

Comment: I had to put the text implicitly, that is `<option th:value="-1">Please Select</option>` to get the option once it had got a value and you wanted to "remove" it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an empty selected option like this:

```
<option disabled="disabled" selected value=" "> -- select an option -- </option>
```

It's disabled, so you won't be able to select it back once you select another option.

Comment: I added the "option disabled selected value" to my option tag and this results in an error.  I tried looking up your example on the Thymeleaf documentation but couldn't find a reference.  Could you please expand upon your answer?

Comment: Changed to be    <option disabled selected value th:each="choice : ${serviceDeptList}"  and I get an error that 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "disabled" associated with an element type "option" must be followed by the ' = ' character.'

Comment: Ok, so it must be `disabled="disabled"` because it's XHTML.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't work either.   Is this even supported by Thymeleaf?  I tried setting the th:selected="-1" but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULL. So nothing is displayed. the NULL as string will be transformed to empty.

```html
 <select id = "reason" th:field="*{reason}">
            <option th:value="NULL" th:text="NULL"></option>
            <option th:value="error" th:text="error"></option>
            <option th:value="timeout" th:text="timeout"></option>
            <option th:value="cancel" th:text="cancel"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me empty option with `""` value.

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled"></option>
```

or

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled"> -- select an option -- </option>
```

I did checked `@NotNull` for id at Java Form.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```html
    <option label="-- No Value Selected --" value=""></option>
```