# Selecting disabled default option with Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I've got a select menu that I've created with Thymeleaf. I need the menu to have no default choice. Usually this is done with a disabled extra option, and that I have done too. Now, the issue is that I just cannot get the **selected** attribute to render into the resulting HTML. This appears to break IE, which then defaults to the first non-disabled option. This is what I've got:

```html
    <select th:field="*{serviceName}" required="required" >
      <option th:selected="true" th:disabled="true" th:value="NOT_SELECTED" th:text="'Pick one'"></option>
      <option th:each="entry : ${form.services}"
              th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}">
      </option>
    </select>
```

and it renders like this:

```html
    <select required="required" id="serviceTechnicalName" name="serviceTechnicalName">
      <option disabled="disabled" value="NOT_SELECTED">Pick one</option>
      <option value="SERVICE1">Service One</option>
      <option value="SERVICE2">Service Two</option>
    </select>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been fiddling with different combinations of these different options for at least an hour already, it shouldn't be this difficult...

FWIW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682866/thyme-leaf-dropdown-list-without-preselecting) appears to be a duplicate question, but the answers there aren't doing it for me. There also isn't an accepted answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [forum post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-lt-select-gt-lt-option-gt-td4029201.html) that [Kimy82 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828111/1333157) goes deep down into some Java configuration hole, so the solution did not appeal to me.

I then upgraded my Spring Boot from 1.3.3-RELEASE to 1.4.0-RELEASE. Then I spent a while trying to upgrade Thymeleaf from version 2 to [version 3](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html), but apparently could not get all the dependencies and excluded transitive dependencies right.

So in the end I did this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('serviceTechnicalName').value='NOT_SELECTED';
});
</script>
```

Now, it's not the answer I was looking for, but it does the job...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when using th:field it does not work. Look at [this post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-lt-select-gt-lt-option-gt-td4029201.html). 
However, I do not think you have to use th:selected as there is no processing in the server. 
Have you tryied something like:

```
<select th:field="*{serviceName}" required="required" >
      <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
      <option th:each="entry : ${form.services}"
              th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}">
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried (and retried) this approach, and it does not work. I am now reading the post you linked, though.